# How to use dispatchTouchEvent?

Tags: android

How can I call an `onTouch` method programmatically by dispatching a fake touch event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try calling `yourView.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain);`

Comment: what to pass in the arguments for obtain method?

Comment: @gaurav See this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html search for obtain method and look for its parameters and select appropriate method for your use.

Comment: ```obtain(long downTime, long eventTime, int action, int pointerCount, PointerProperties[] pointerProperties, PointerCoords[] pointerCoords, int metaState, int buttonState, float xPrecision, float yPrecision, int deviceId, int edgeFlags, int source, int flags)``` LOL! I am mad with params.