# ontouch not work when setBuiltInZoomControls true in webview in android

Tags: android, webview

I am working on webview in android.and my code is below

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler(this);
private WebView wv;


wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wv = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            String data = "<html><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />"
                    + "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; min-scale=1.0; max-scale=3.0; \" />"
                    + "<body>"
                    + "<div style=\"text-align:center;width:100&#37;\">"
                    + "Murti"
                    + "</div> <br/><div>"
                    + "Touch and hold one of the customizable icons, then drag it to Remove. Touch ... The controls appear under your finger, and you can slide to a control and select it. ... Find apps with the biggest Wi-Fi data usage, then reduce their sync"
                    + "</div><br/><br/><br/><br/></body></html>";
            wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", data,
                    "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
wv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (v.getId() == R.id.webView1
                            && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1, 500);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg.what == 1) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "WebView clicked",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

isuue is that when i pinch zoom on webview than zoomingcontroll visible and after that ontouch not working.without zooming ontouch is work fine.

Comment: myWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

It just stops to show the controls, pinch-zoom support is still available.

Comment: but it is not work in android 2.2

Comment: wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);.. then they remove button zoom in out .. and simply worked

Comment: but it also stop zooming

Comment: you are implement this .. or not

Comment: i am implement your suggestion but not work. it is stop zooming

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21113/discussion-between-urveshpatel50-and-altaf)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `OnTouchListener` and use instead of it dispatchTouchEvent

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setDescendantFocusability(int)

Create your own class that extend WebView and overide `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)`:

```
public class MyWebView extend WebView {

    //constructor 

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // code
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
};
```

If you want to know more about dispatcher, welcome here [How to use dispatchtouchevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564677/how-to-use-dispatchtouchevent) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907194/android-singletap-onclick-in-webview), [onintercepttouchevent and ACTION_DOWN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283827/onintercepttouchevent-only-gets-action-down) and so on...