# Android: Swipe using HID

Tags: android, swipe, hid

I want to implement android swiping mechanism using a HID (Human Interface Device).

For example, if I click button X on my HID, it should be equivalent to swiping left on my android device. Can anyone let me know how to implement this?

**EDIT:**
I am able to create a custom event using MotionEvent.Obtain. However, I want to execute this event irrespective of what is opened on the screen. For example: I created an event for Right Swipe. If my app is running in background, and android OS menu is opened, then I want to run that event on the OS menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) to send a user-defined `MotionEvent` to the `Activity`.

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9564677/1321873) to know how this can be achieved.

Comment: I am able to create a custom event using MotionEvent.Obtain. However, I want to execute this event irrespective of what is opened on the screen. For example: I created an event for Right Swipe. If my app is running in background, and android OS menu is opened, then I want to run that event on the OS menu.